# How to create mouse double listener to java jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, mouse-listeners

I have java jtable  and i want to use mouse double click event on it ,and i have got many codes to stick listener to the table put unable to stick it to working with my code and tired reading tens of listener code here and there, am a new to Java and need more patient and easy direct help and some professional inside **stack** not give or afford such essential questions, I sensed the same due many attempts in the past to have explanation for some dim code to me i have got devoted as help only ?!  hope i will be lucky this time !
Last all avaialble listener code in stack working with table brought from the designer and not working with mine created by code dont know why perhaps this is my main problem .

```
  public  class JFband  extends javax.swing.JFrame  {
    Connection con1;
    Statement stmt1;
    ResultSet rs1;
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    String fLag;
    DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    static String Bno;

            JTable  jTnameSearch = new JTable(tableModel);
     private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter
            = new TableRowSorter<>();


    // declare sorter to sort JTable data based on jTsearch Box field entry 


    public JFband() {

      this.setLayout(null);
     // here is the code with error :

      jTnameSearch.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){ 
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
      if (e.getClickCount() == 2){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the double click code is working");

        }
      }
     } );

      }

       }

     // listener for my jTable 

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed"   desc="Generated                            Code">                          



    public  void LoadTable(){
                try {
            String host1= "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/accountingsystem";
            String uName1="adamin";
            String uPass1="1234a1234b";
            String sql1;
            con1=DriverManager.getConnection(host1,uName1 ,uPass1);
            //String sql ="select * from log where password= jTuser.getText()  " ;
         if (fLag.equals("search"))
            sql1="select  band_name,band_no ,band_type from band order by band_no ";
           else
            sql1="select  band_name,band_no ,band_type from band where band_name='" +filterText.getText()+ "' order by band_no ";
            stmt1=con1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs=stmt1.executeQuery(sql1);
            int jCounter=0; 
            while (rs.next()){ jCounter++;
            }
  if (jCounter==0) 
     return;
         rs.beforeFirst();
                String[]   columnnames = {"اسم الحساب","رقم الحساب","نوع الحساب"};
               String Data[][]=new String[jCounter][3];
                  int j=0;
           while (rs.next()) {
        //    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  i+"فاصل   "+ jCounter);
               Data[j][0]=rs.getString("band_name"); 
           Data[j][1]=  rs.getString("band_no");
     Data[j][2]=  rs.getString("band_type");
              ++j;
                        }    
                    //   DefaultTableModel tableModel;
            tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(Data,columnnames);
           jTnameSearch = new JTable(tableModel) {   // القوس هذا جديد اضيف لعمل شرط عدم امكانية الكتابة 
               // في الجدول اصبح خمسة سطر 
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)  
            {  
         return false;  
            }  
        };
        //  انتهت دالة منع الكتابة 
           //only single selection mode
           jTnameSearch.setSelectionMode(0);
          rowSorter  = new TableRowSorter<>(jTnameSearch.getModel());
               jTnameSearch.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
                        jSpane3.setViewportView(jTnameSearch);
            jTnameSearch.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            //jTnameSearch.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); // enable sort and filter
              jPsearch.setVisible(true);
            jPanel2.setVisible(false);
            filterText.requestFocus();
            rs.close();
            fLag="text";
                 }

        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
    }
    }

   }
```

Comment: Please consider add a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of dump all your code here. Some hints: 1) Don't mix null layout with layout managers. Just use the last ones. 2) Instead of KeyListener use appropriate listeners. In general ActionListener to catch "Enter" key pressed on a text field or selection changes in a combo box, DocumentListener to listen for text changes in a text component. 3) Separate the database connection code from your GUI. In a multi-tiered design those belong to different layers.

Comment: hi i already faced your problem what you have to do is to first check if the selected row is the same in the previous click i did it for deleting data i will give you my code try to make it useful your way.

Comment: @dic19 thank you your advises i have read it and attempt to reduce my code accordingly .

Comment: i checked mouse listener to jtable imported from the desinger it's working case the table from design and not working in my case when the jtable created by code any help ? why the code not effecting the code jtable and working in design table ?

Answer (score 1):

i made a click event attached to the jtable :

```
    int ClickCount=0,selectedTodelete=-1;

    private void JTArticleJPAddArrticleMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                    

    if (ClickCount==1) {
        // your double click section code here
                 return;
    }else{
            if (selectedTodelete==JTArticleJPAddArrticle.getSelectedRow()) {
                ClickCount++;
              //here we are checking that the event is on the same row (double click on the same row)
        }else{

                ClickCount=0;
                selectedTodelete=JTArticleJPAddArrticle.getSelectedRow();
                // the new cell selected
        }

    }

    //one click event code here
}
```

that my way of making a double click event anywhere it work greatly for me

that the table instantiation code it may help you understanding why is not working for you

```
JTArticleJPAddArrticle = new javax.swing.JTable();

JTArticleJPAddArrticle.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));

JTArticleJPAddArrticle.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
new Object [][] {

},
new String [] {
    "Reference","Libellé","Marque","Type","Prix d'achat","Prix de vente","Quantité","Total","Etat"
   }
){
boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
    false, false, false, false
};
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return false;
    }
 });



 JTArticleJPAddArrticle.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
   public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        JTArticleJPAddArrticleMouseClicked(evt);// that a function called in the event mouseClicked
   }
 });

      jScrollPane8.setViewportView(JTArticleJPAddArrticle);
```

Comment: thank you but what's the JTArticleJPAddArrticle is it your jtbale name and what is the benefit of deleteCount integer variable

Comment: the code is working with swing design jtable but not working for my jtable created by code any help

Comment: i checked mouse listener to jtable imported from the desinger it's working case the table from design and not working in my case when the jtable created by code any help ? why the code not effecting the code jtable and working in design table ?

Comment: hi JTArticleJPAddArticle is my jtable for the list of articles deletcount is the mouse click count and selectedTodelete is the selected row @MohamedBawaneen

Comment: Thank you i have noticed your JTArticleJPAddArticle and code working fine for jtable from the designer but if created by code it's not working i dont know what's missing or what i have to add to jtable properties .

Comment: @MohamedBawaneen send me the code you r doing may be there is a little error

Comment: wait i m gonna give you my jtable instanciantion code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67907/discussion-between-mohammed-housseyn-taleb-and-mohamed-bawaneen).